# Result “almost doubles” on Try It Online for Project Euler

Tags: esoteric-languages

This code is for Project Euler Problem 1. It appears to work [here](http://ajanse.me/asciidots/demo/), but on Try It Online (tio.run) the result appears to "almost double" (twice the expected result minus 1). It seems like every number is added twice. Is it possible to fix it?

```
`,`                              /-------\
`,`                            .->---{+}-~-$#&
`,`                     /------->-----^  |
`,`                    /*\     /*\    |  |
`,`                /---~-+\/---~-+\   |  |
`,`                |   ! |||   ! ||   |  |
`,` .-#1000->*-{-}-*#3[%]|\*#5[%]|\*#0/  |
`,`         |\#1/  \---/ | \---/ | |     |
`,`         |            \------->->-----*
`,`         \----------------------------/
```

Test case for smaller constant:

```
`,`                              /-------\
`,`                            .->---{+}-~-$#&
`,`                     /------->-----^  |
`,`                    /*\     /*\    |  |
`,`                /---~-+\/---~-+\   |  |
`,`                |   ! |||   ! ||   |  |
`,` .-#10--->*-{-}-*#3[%]|\*#5[%]|\*#0/  |
`,`         |\#1/  \---/ | \---/ | |     |
`,`         |            \------->->-----*
`,`         \----------------------------/
```

(Prints 23 on Aaron, and 45 on Try It Online)

Comment: It's AsciiDots.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Community This is the entire code.